# React onClick not firing inside map generated list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple list being displayed on the return value of a fetch call. I have some functions firing on selection of an item, but for the life of me, I can't fire the onClick event. I have events bound outside the map that work just fine (the onKeyUp and down), but the onClick while inside the map does not work. Not sure where to go from there.

```
handleClick() {
// won't fire
        console.log('test')
    }

render() { 
        return (
            <div className="autocomplete">
                <input type="text" placeholder={this.props.fieldName} onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp} onClick={this.handleClick} />
                <div className="autocomplete__list" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    <ul>
                        {this.state.list.map((item, index) => <li key={index} className={this.checkActive(index)} onClick={this.handleClick}>{item.firstName}</li>)}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

No errors thrown, the method does nothing when clicking those fields. If it matters at all, the "list" is absolutely positioned. And here is the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            list: [],
            cursor: 0
        }
        this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this)
        this.handleKeyUp = this.handleKeyUp.bind(this)
        this.checkActive = this.checkActive.bind(this)
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }
```

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Have you tried `onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}` ?

Comment: Yeah, that also fires nothing

Comment: why do you have the onClick even for multiple elements? like your input and your parent div. I think the issue is the parent div click is preventing the click on the child. check your z index's

Comment: I was testing the event to see if it would fire if I moved it. You may be correct, I'll dig into the call stack

Comment: just remove it from the div and see what happens.. or just add a high z-index to each `li`. if that fixes it i can write up an answer real quick :)

Comment: I think it's the z-index, whoops! Feel free to write it up as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be either:

1. You have the same handler on a parent element that wraps all of your `li`'s.. Usually the click event would bubble upwards from the children to the parent so this is unlikely.
2. Your `li`'s are a lower z-index than the parent element. Which means that the `li` elements lay under an element. so a click event only happens on the element on the top.

Try adding this to your css

```
.autocomplete__list li {
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the click handler was attached to the parent (and other) elements to see if I could get it to fire. The problem was the z-index itself, which will not fire an error (because the event is not fired at all), because the element was overlayed with other elements.